# Defining dependencies for multiple variants

Tags: android, gradle

Say we have four build types: debug, qa, beta, and release.

We can define dependencies for specific variants like so:

```
dependencies {
    // These dependencies are only included for debug and qa builds
    debugCompile 'com.example:lib:1.0.0'
    qaCompile 'com.example:lib:1.0.0'
}
```

Is there a way to compile these dependencies for multiple variants without repeating the artifact descriptor?

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
dependencies {
   internalCompile 'com.example:lib:1.0.0'
}
```

Where `internalCompile` would specify that the library is included for both `debug` and `qa` builds.

I believe that the solution lies within defining a new [Gradle configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:configurations), but if I create an `internalCompile` configuration I am unsure how to ensure that those dependencies are only compiled for `qa` and `debug` builds.

Comment: If I am interpreting the docs correctly, there are already configurations for your build types (e.g., `configurations.qaCompile`). You might look into the object model for those and see if you can rig up a copy mechanism, akin to how we define new product flavors based off an existing one. Then, you could build up the common pieces using one configuration (e.g., `debugCompile`), have the Groovy code to clone that setup into the other configuration (e.g., `qaCompile`), then continue defining the dependencies that are unique.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I hadn't gone down the route of trying to copy the dependencies between versions because I was hoping there was a more straightforward way to do it built in to Gradle. My other thought was to leverage flavor dimensions to define an "internal" dimension I could use for these dependencies.

Comment: The problem with the flavor approach is that you will be forevermore having to deal with that flavor in your build stuff (e.g., you're not building `debug`, you're building `debugInternal`), if I am understanding your plan. Another option: `qaCompile` and kin support an array of artifact names, in addition to individual names. You could define the array in one spot, then apply it twice. This does not precisely address your stated concern, but if you are mostly interested in ensuring that the common dependencies are only declared once, it would be another approach to the problem.

Comment: The array option is definitely one to consider. I agree that the flavor option isn't ideal for the reasons you mentioned, and is why I had been hoping to avoid it.

Comment: Gradle configurations can "extend" from each other. You can either have a downstream config inherit everything from an upstream config + additional stuff, or you can declare a new common config that everyone inherits from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **extendsFrom**
>
> The names of the configurations which this configuration extends from. The artifacts of the super configurations are also available in this configuration.

```
configurations {
    // debugCompile and qaCompile are already created by the Android Plugin
    internalCompile
}

debugCompile.extendsFrom(internalCompile)
qaCompile.extendsFrom(internalCompile)

dependencies {
    //this adds lib to both debugCompile and qaCompile
    internalCompile 'com.example:lib:1.0.0'
}
```

#### Alternatively:

You can create a collection of artifact descriptors and use it with multiple configurations.

```
List internalCompile = ["com.example:lib:1.0.0",
               "commons-cli:commons-cli:1.0@jar",
               "org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.4@jar"]

List somethingElse = ['org.hibernate:hibernate:3.0.5@jar',
                  'somegroup:someorg:1.0@jar']

dependencies {
    debugCompile internalCompile
    qaCompile internalCompile, somethingElse
}
```

Comment: Can you change the inheritance of existing configurations this way? We're not defining `debugCompile` and `qaCompile` directly -- they are being created by the Android plugin.

Comment: I know that you can add an `extendsFrom` to configs added by the java plugin. I haven't tested with android configs. Also added an alternative approach.

Comment: I had previously assumed that `extendsFrom` was like Java inheritance- only one parent per configuration. [Indeed it is actually a Set](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:extendsFrom). Unfortunately it doesn't look like this works, and I think it is due to a timing issue with [when the plugin calls `setExtendsFrom()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/69c4b95102b4b9862bfba68b3eaf5b7537a705ee/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/dependency/VariantDependencies.groovy#64)

Comment: @Tanis.7x From what I can tell, the android configs are added during plugin `apply()`. Wonder if there is a way to ensure that `extendsFrom` is run after `apply()`. Does the second approach not work for you?

Comment: The second approach will work, but I like the first a lot better. I will play with it and see if I can get it to work correctly.

Comment: Is there an error message? or do the dependencies not get inherited, silently?

Comment: @Tanis.7x didn't try myself, but worth a try: `qaCompile.extendsFrom(internalCompile)`. It's possible that if a configuration already exists the setup closure is not run (you can easily confirm by adding `println` inside).

Comment: It was failing silently. @TWiStErRob's solution worked though!

Comment: Neat! updating answer.